# Mapping `apply` to List of Functions

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#higher-orderism) demonstrates mapping with currying:

```
*Main> let xs = map (*) [1..3]
```

xs now equals [(1*), (2*), (3*)]

**EDITED** to correct order per [Antal S-Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237428/antal-s-z)'s comment.

We can get the first item in the list, and apply 3 to it - returning 3*1.

```
*Main> (xs !! 0) 3
3
```

But, how can I apply the below `foo` to apply `1` to all curried functions in `xs`?

```
*Main> let foo = 1
*Main> map foo xs

<interactive>:160:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `(Integer -> Integer) -> b0'
                with actual type `Integer'
    In the first argument of `map', namely `foo'
    In the expression: map foo xs
    In an equation for `it': it = map foo xs
```

Desired output:

`[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: A small point: `map (*) [1..3]` produces the list `[(1*),(2*),(3*)]`.  For multiplication, the order doesn't matter, but it does in the general case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `($)` function...

```
Prelude> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

...passing just the second argument to it.

```
Prelude> let foo = 2
Prelude> map ($ foo) [(1*), (2*), (3*)]
[2,4,6]
```

Comment: "Mean" is probably a bit too strong, but the fact is that `($)` is just function application packaged as a convenient operator. You'll see it all the time being used to minimise parentheses usage (e.g. `abs $ 2 - 3` instead of `abs (2 - 3)`. Note that the `(<*>)` operator Aadit M. Shah mentions in his answer is sometimes pronounced as "apply".

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using [applicative functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors)?

```
import Control.Applicative

main = (*) <$> [1,2,3] <*> pure 1
```

The `<$>` function is the same as `fmap` in infix form. It has the type signature:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The `<*>` function is the functor equivalent of `$` (function application):

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The `pure` function is similar to `return` for monads. It takes a normal value and returns an applicative functor:

```
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
```

Hence the expression `(*) <$> [1,2,3] <*> pure 1` is similar to applying the `(*)` function to all the values of `[1,2,3]` and `pure 1`. Since `pure 1` only has one value it is equivalent to multiplying every item of the list with `1` to produce a new list of products.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use anonymous function:

```
map (\x -> x foo) xs
```